# SQL Query with SUM Aggregate with Effectivedate and group by

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by, sum

I have simplified my SQL Query in a sample Way as below.
I am having an EmployeeTran Table with Following Records.

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeTran (
    EMPID int NOT NULL,
    Effectivedate datetime,
    Amount INT   
);

insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-01',300);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-02',200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-03',200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-04',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-05',900);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-06',600);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-07',700);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-08',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-09',1100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-10',2200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-11',400);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-12',600);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-13',500);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-14',300);
insert into EmployeeTran values(101,'2017-01-15',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-01',300);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-02',300);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-03',700);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-04',200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-05',200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-06',2800);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-07',700);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-08',900);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-09',1100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-10',2200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-11',1100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-12',600);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-13',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-14',300);
insert into EmployeeTran values(102,'2017-01-15',900);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-01',900);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-02',200);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-03',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-04',800);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-05',1100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-06',600);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-07',500);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-08',400);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-09',100);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-10',1400);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-11',400);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-12',600);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-13',700);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-14',1000);
insert into EmployeeTran values(103,'2017-01-15',1800);
```

In the above table, we are having 3 Employees Transaction amount from 1st Jan to 15th Jan for each day.
If we want the Transaction sum from  starting to a particular selection date,
we can use below Query to obtain the same

```
Declare @selectiondate Date
select  @selectiondate='2017-01-04'
select et.EMPID,Sum(Amount) AS SUM from EmployeeTran et
where et.effectivedate<=@selectiondate
group by et.EMPID
```

Above Query will give sum from 1st jan to 4th Jan for each Employee as below
[Image is added as Link as lack of enough reputation Point][https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLBIg.jpg]

Now, we want to add one additional Column in Above select Query as Effectivedtae.
We need to pass a range of dates using @selectiondate and @enddate.
Query should give sum for each date from the starting.
i.e. If we pass date range from 4th Jan to 9th Jan, then it should give sum for each dates as below.

we need to do modification is below Query.

```
Declare @selectiondate Date
Declare @enddate Date
select  @selectiondate='2017-01-04'
select  @enddate='2017-01-09'

select et.EMPID,Sum(Amount) AS SUM from EmployeeTran et
where et.effectivedate<=@selectiondate
group by et.EMPID
```

[Image added as Link][https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI7dl.jpg]

Please assist for above Query.

Comment: Please try to edit you post in order to include sample table data as well formatted text instead of images.

Comment: did you find my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

@Mihir Amin, what you wan to achieve is called a [Running Total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total).

To completely resolve this, we have to extend @Tyron78's answer:

```
DECLARE @selectionDate DATE = '2017-01-04',
        @endDate DATE = '2017-01-09';

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  
        EMPID,
        Effectivedate,
        Amount,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY Effectivedate) AS AggAmount
    FROM 
        EmployeeTran
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE Effectivedate BETWEEN @selectionDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following in order to evaluate the sum to the corresponding date and use the result within a subquery if required:

```
SELECT  EMPID,
        Effectivedate,
        Amount,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY Effectivedate) AS AggAmount
  FROM @EmployeeTran
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.it will give you better performance beacuse.Here i'm first fetching data between two specific dates and then grouping up based on empid rather than fetching all the unwanted data and grouping up based on empid for specific dates.

```
DECLARE @selectionDate DATE = '2017-01-04',
        @endDate DATE = '2017-01-09';

select EMPID,Effectivedate,Amount,SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY Effectivedate) AS AggAmount from (
SELECT  EMPID,Effectivedate,Amount
FROM EmployeeTran
where Effectivedate BETWEEN @selectionDate AND @endDate
) as a
```